# VPN server on windows 10 not working properly

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, ip

I used to set a VPN server on a windows 7 machine and it worked fine. It never had any problems if I used another machine to connect to it and tried connect to internet. And if I try to see my public IP address on the client machine, it always showed my server machine's IP address.

But I just set a VPN on a windows 10 machine, I still can use another machine to connect to this one. But the client machine is no longer able to connect to internet. I cannot open any website. But the VPN connection is fine.
I tried uncheck the "Use default gateway" checkbox in TCP IPV4 properties, then I could indeed have internet connect on the client machine. But the problem is, if I tried to see my public IP address on the client machine, it shows its own IP address instead of the server's IP address. But I want it to use the server's IP address.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check this post "[OpenVPN not default gateway for all traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/648118/openvpn-not-default-gateway-for-all-traffic)". There is an explanation of some trouble like you post and the solution

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Im not using OpenVPN. I am only using the windows's own feature. Like this: http://pureinfotech.com/setup-vpn-server-windows-10/